# calculate unique session per visitor in R

Tags: r, sqldf

I have the following table and I would like to calculate the number of unique sessions assuming that : if the same visitor(Browsers) has two siquential timestamps with more than 30 min difference then these should be considered as two unique sessions.

Browsers is uniquely identifies each user
timestamp is date with time
Page is url page

```
Browsers    timestamp             Page
  x        2014-01-01 14:15:33     1
  x        2014-01-01 14:16:33     2
  x        2014-01-01 14:17:33     3
  x        2014-01-01 16:15:33     1
  y        2014-01-01 16:20:33     5
  y        2014-01-01 16:25:33     2
```

So based on the logic given and the above dummy table I should get 3 unique sessions. 2 for Browsers x and 1 for Browsers y

I am fairly new with R so I have no clue how to even start. Any help or suggestion to read something relevant is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do with runs? E.g., if Browser `z` has timestamps a 8:00, 8:20, and 8:40, is this 1 session?

Comment: Exactly! In my dataset. each row in my data set represent a visit to one page of my site. column browsers represent the ID of the user. Each user can either visit 1 page and leave or click to more pages. if for the same visitor the sequential timestamp is greater than 30 min then those two should be identified as two different visits

Comment: Is your timestamp column already a useful POSIX class or is it a character or factor?

Comment: It was a UTC which I used the POSIXct fn to convert it to local time so yes it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using `data.table`:

```
setDT(df)[order(timestamp), .(uniSession = sum(diff(timestamp) > 30) + 1), .(Browsers)]
   Browsers uniSession
1:        x          2
2:        y          1
```

Comment: It works but I dont need the sum per Browsers ( sorry if I were misleading in my attempt to make sure the logic is understood) as I have thousands of them and it not useful. Instead I want a more aggregated value either total or ideally grouped by another column lets say for argument's sake platform.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the total for the whole data set retaining the logic(effectively the sum of the result of your script)

Comment: You can add another summary session after. i.e. `setDT(df)[order(timestamp), .(uniSession = sum(diff(timestamp) > 30) + 1), .(Browsers)][, .(sumUniSessions = sum(uniSession))]`, this will give `sumUniSessions` as 3.

Comment: Thank you. last thing, Can I group those sessions by an other column of my data set. even in two steps. e.g. add this column on your first session and then add by=col.name on your second session

Comment: It depends on what your column is, if it doesn't intersect the Browser, by which I mean, every Browser has only one unique value for that column, then you can add the column to the group variable in both sessions. Other wise, you may need to redefine your logic.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Browsers) %>%
   arrange(timestamp) %>%
   summarise(uniSession = sum(diff(timestamp) > 30) + 1)
```